Search or dump Chrome debugger console
I need to find a piece of code in Chrome's / Edge's debugger console that I wrote some time ago. You can "scroll" through it with the up-arrow-key, but it's tedious and resets itself each time you stop to check something so you need to start from the beginning.
Instead of doing this in the console, I'd rather search a file, but the question is where that file may be? Do you know where Chrome/Edge is storing the console history?
